# php form not sending

Tags: php, forms, email, submit

I am trying to send a form that it has taken me about 3 days to manage to build! I am really struggling with php but learning. Anyway, I have done what I think is correct but my form is not getting to me? I hope this is an easy fix! Code is as follows and I really appreciate any help:

```
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $addDateErr = $nameErr = $emailErr = $subjectErr = $messageErr = $questionErr = "";
    $addDate = $name = $email = $subject = $message = $WebSearch = $SocialMedia =      $WordOfMouth = $Other ="";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
//Date
   if (empty($_POST["addDate"]))
   {$comment = "";}
   else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["addDate"]);}

//Name
    if (empty($_POST["name"]))
    {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
    else
    {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
    {
    $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
    }

//Email
   if (empty($_POST["email"]))
   {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
   else
   {
   $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
   {
   $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
   }
   }

//Subject
   if (empty($_POST["subject"]))
   {$comment = "";}
   else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["subject"]);}

//Message
   if (empty($_POST["message"]))
   {$messageErr = "A message is required";}
   else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["message"]);}

//Question
    if (isset($_POST['question']))
    {
    $menuVar = $_POST['question'];
    } else {
    $menuVar = "----------";}
}
function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
?>

<form method="post" id="form" action="send.php">
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p><br />
    <!--<form method="post" id="form" action="<php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);>">-->

    <!--Date--><div class="contact-font">
        Date Photography needed (if necessary)<br />
        <input type="text" name="addDate" id="datepicker" size="25" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['addDate'])) {echo $_POST['addDate']; } ?>">
    </div>

    <!--Name--><div class="contact-font" style=" margin-top: 20px;">
        <span class="asterix">* </span>Name:<br />
        <input type="text" name="name" class="border" size="25" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) {echo $_POST['name']; } ?>">
        <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    </div>

    <!--Email--><div class="contact-font" style=" margin-top: 20px;">
        <span class="asterix">* </span>Email: (please double check enty)<br />
        <input type="text" name="email" class="border" size="25" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) {echo $_POST['email']; } ?>"><span class="error">
        <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
    </div>

    <!--Subject--><div class="contact-font" style=" margin-top: 20px;">
        Subject:<br />
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="border" size="25" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['subject'])) {echo $_POST['subject']; } ?>">
    </div>

    <!--Message--><div class="contact-font" style=" margin-top: 20px;">
        <span class="asterix">* </span>Message:<br />
        <textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="message" class="border"><?php if(isset($_POST['message'])) {echo $_POST['message']; } ?></textarea>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $messageErr;?></span> 
    </div><br />

        <select name="question">
            <option <?php if($menuVar=="----------") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="----------">----------</option>
            <option <?php if($menuVar=="WebSearch") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="WebSearch">Web Search</option>
            <option <?php if($menuVar=="SocialMedia") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="SocialMedia">Social Media</option>
            <option <?php if($menuVar=="Wordofmouth") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Wordofmouth">Word of mouth</option>
            <option <?php if($menuVar=="Other") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
    </div>
</form>


       <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({minDate: 129, maxDate: "+5Y", changeMonth: true,changeYear: true, showButtonPanel: true, dateFormat: 'dd MM yy'});
    });

    $('#form').on('submit', function(){
    return $('#email').val() == $('#emailConfirmation').val();
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .asterix{color: #bc2021;font-size: 20px;}
    .contact-font, #info-req, #opening-text{font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-weight: 100; color: #000;}
    .border:focus{border: 2px solid #bc2021;}
    #datepicker:focus{border: 2px solid #bc2021;}
    .error {color: #FF0000;}
    #marketing{border: 1px solid black; width: 150px; height: 22px;}
    #submit{width: 100px; height: 25px; font-size: 15px;}
    #submit:active{background-color: #bc2021;}
</style>
```

Below is the send.php file contents:

```
<?php
$addDate = $_POST['addDate'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$question = $_POST['question'];

$to = "some@email.com";
$subject = "Help!";

$body = "Please do not reply!";

mail($to,$subject,$body);

echo "Message Sent!<a href='index.html'>Home</a>";

?>
```

Comment: Please define/explain "not getting to me"

Comment: Your `{` braces are difficult to follow. I think that's your problem.

Comment: Apologies, I did not add the sent.php code. I have added it now. When I open the form (not locally) fill it in and send it I get the message saying "Message Sent!" but no email comes to me?

Comment: Is your server setup correctly to send mail?

Comment: Server is fine yes. I have another form on the same server that works.

Comment: can you enclose your `mail()` function in a `var_dump()` function? for instance: `var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $body));`, run the script, then tell us what `var_dump` outputs? It'll either say `boolean(false)` or `boolean(true)`.

Comment: I will try to now yes.

Comment: bool(true) Message Sent!Home     that is the result of var_dump

Comment: That would indicate that PHP has successfully sent the email to the mail server, which indicates your PHP is fine. There are 2 other things to narrow down now. Check your junk folder (I guess you already have but gotta suggest it!). Also, it could be a slowdown in the mail queue, a slow send, (sometimes it could take a few hours for an email to come through). If it still doesn't arrive, try checking your mail server error log.

Comment: hmm, well I am very happy to know the code is working ok, that is something after all the time spent on the project! Nothing in the Junk mail but yes worth a look for sure. Also the other email I sent from the server (from another totally basic form) was received within a few seconds of being sent. It makes sense that the php is good after boolean true I guess that indicates the file was posted. I have no idea now though. I guess I will have to just wait and hope it arrives....